# Javascript Malware attacks

Tags: magento-1.9, security

Our shop get repeatedly infected with a "crypto-miner" malware. Its a javascript code that mines cryptocurrency on the client's CPU.

Everytime this happens I can find and remove the code in the Backend under:

System->General->Design->HTML Head->Miscellaneous Scripts

We use Magento  1.9.3.7 with the latest security patches. I also changed the admin password but it doesn't help.

I would like to know how to prevent these attacks to happen again.

Comment: Look in the php files, i remember i read a post about a hack which saves malicious code in config. But to really fix it you should diff your core with a vanilla magento. Also there are some nice shell scripts out there to find hacks in source files.

Comment: What tool do you recommend to compare diff with vanilla or to find hacks in source files?

Comment: Even if you use Magento with all latest patches, it's possible you are using some outdated/exploitable 3rd party extensions. It's important to find out when and where things go wrong, so maybe try to look through webserver access/error logs, change passwords etc. I've seen a similar case with a fully patched Magento shop which had code injected in HTML header/footer via Magmi because the DB credentials where accessible via browser. good luck!

Comment: i suggest https://github.com/gwillem/magento-malware-scanner

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you use Magento with all latest patches, it's possible you are using some **outdated/exploitable 3rd party extensions**.

It's important to find out **when and where things go wrong**, so maybe try to look through **webserver access/error logs**, change passwords etc.

I've seen a similar case with a fully patched Magento shop which had code injected in HTML header/footer via Magmi because the DB credentials where accessible via browser.

Good luck!